# Get notifications for my FB page

Tags: iphone, ios, facebook

Allow me to describe my final goal:
I'm running a Facebook page and I'd like my users to also have the option to install my branded iPhone app which will show them all the posts in the page (only root posts-no need to present comments).

The app should also support push-notifications (upon each new post to the page), and also have the ability to analyze all the posts and present them in sorted order (by number of likes).

I went through the new FB API and couldn't really figure a direction to go.

Any idea how should I implement this?

10x

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can try the facebook sdk for iOS.

1. for show posts in the page, you can request a ${pageId}/feed via Facebook object. something like this. Here is the [page object](http://developers.facebook.com/docs/reference/api/page/).

   ```
   [facebook requestWithGraphPath:@"pageId/feed" andDelegate:self];
   ```
2. push notification, you have to check if there is a new feed in the page for maybe every 2 mins in your server by checking the same ${pageId}/feed. And if there is a new post in the ${pageId}/feed, you can push the content to your fans.
3. After you get the data(which is a post object) from ${pageId}/feed in the iphone, you can store them into core data. There is a field "likes" in the [post](http://developers.facebook.com/docs/reference/api/post/) object for you to order by.